# How to solve this logical error (beginner)?

Tags: java, if-statement, runtime-error, bluej

I am taking an intro to Java programming and I have the below assignment. I think my code is correct but I get the wrong answer. I need to find the total cost for each car, and "buy" the cheaper one. Suppose that I am traveling 50000 miles:

- Fuel cost = $4
- Miles driven = 50000
- Purchase price for car 1 = $15000
- Purchase price for car 2 = $30000
- Mpg for car 1 = 10
- Mpg for car 2 = 50

gas cost  = (Miles driven / Mpg) * Fuel cost

total cost = Purchase price + gas cost

and here is my code:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int milesDriven = 50000;
        int mpg1 = 10;
        int mpg2 = 50;
        int pricePerGallon = 4;
        int purchasePrice1 = 15000;
        int purchasePrice2 = 30000;
        int gasCost4Car1 = (milesDriven / mpg1) * pricePerGallon;
        int gasCost4Car2 = (milesDriven / mpg2) * pricePerGallon;
        int total4Car1 = (purchasePrice1 + gasCost4Car1);
        int total4Car2 = (purchasePrice2 + gasCost4Car2);

        if(total4Car1 < total4Car2) 
        {
            System.out.println(total4Car1 + gasCost4Car1);
        }
            else
            {
            System.out.println(purchasePrice2 + gasCost4Car2);
        }

       System.out.println(purchasePrice2 + gasCost4Car2); // just to see the output for car 2
    }
}
```

The output I get is 34000
and I believe that for car 1 the output should be 35000
and the output for car 2 should be 34000
I don't understand I am getting the wrong answer.
Note: I can't post pictures (for reputation reasons) nor videos, but I am willing to provide that information if needed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on this line:

```
System.out.println(total4Car1 + gasCost4Car1);
```

`total4Car1` already includes `gasCost4Car1`.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/kkIB6Y) printing `34000`.

Answer (score 0):

total4car1 is not less than total4car2, so it prints the total for car 2 i.e. `purchaseprice2 + gascost4car2`, and then it prints it again in  `System.out.println(purchasePrice2 + gasCost4Car2); // just to see the output for car 2`. What should be output?

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up a little bit, gives correct results:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int milesDriven = 50000;
    int mpg1 = 10;
    int mpg2 = 50;
    int pricePerGallon = 4;
    int purchasePrice1 = 15000;
    int purchasePrice2 = 30000;
    int gasCost4Car1 = milesDriven / mpg1 * pricePerGallon;
    int gasCost4Car2 = milesDriven / mpg2 * pricePerGallon;
    int total4Car1 = purchasePrice1 + gasCost4Car1;
    int total4Car2 = purchasePrice2 + gasCost4Car2;

    System.out.println("Total car 1: " + total4Car1);
    System.out.println("Total car 2: " + total4Car2);

    if (total4Car1 < total4Car2) {
        System.out.println("Car 1 is cheaper: " + total4Car1);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Car 2 is cheaper: " + total4Car2);
    }
}
```